# Python and mypy: creating a generic collection with typebound based on a Protocol

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy, structural-typing

I'd like to create a generic container class, where the bounds on the type are based on implementing a protocol, like this:

```
class Nameable(Protocol):
    def name(self) -> str:
        ...


T = TypeVar("T", bound=Nameable)


class NameableList(Generic[T]):
   ...


class Foo:
    _name: str
    def name(self) -> str:
        return self._name


x = NameableList[Foo]
```

In doing this, mypy insists that Foo must be a subtype of Nameable -- which is not what I want (Foo just implements the Nameable protocol)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I just realized that the bound enforces the subtyping requirement. which still keeps my original question alive - how do we enforce a Protocol constraint on the generic type?

Comment: I do not see any mypy error in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As fas as I can see and understand this already does what you want.

For example when I try

```py
y = NameableList[int]
```

I get the following mypy error:

```
protocols.py:22: error: Type argument "builtins.int" of "NameableList" must be a subtype of "Nameable"
protocols.py:22: error: Value of type variable "T" of "NameableList" cannot be "int"
Found 2 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

I.e. the generic allows `Foo` because it adheres to the protocol (not because it inherits from `Nameable`), but does not allow `int` because it does not.

I'm using Python 3.9.2 and mypy==0.812. Perhaps you're using an older version which does not support this properly yet?

Comment: Yes, this works - I had some other issues in my own code which was causing the problem.